# How to bind objects with ListBox to get their properties after selecting with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I'm working on a chat,I have `listbox`, where I show users. I also have UserViewModel with some fields.

```
 public class UserViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to add objects to listbox in case if their Firstname&&Lastname are not null, show their Name, otherwise show their Username. I also need to get their id after selecting any item in listbox. So, after loading the page, I got user list from database, and trying to add to listbox using foreach loop.

Here is xaml code for adding items in listbox.

```
<ListBox 
            Name="usersListBox"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Background="LightGreen"
            Margin="10"
            FontSize="15"
            FontWeight="Medium"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            Loaded="ListBox_Loaded"
            ItemSource = {Binding UsersList}
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel> 
                        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path Username}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

I tried to do the same thing with c# code(So, I commented the whole `<ListBox.Itemtemplate>` tag, removed ItemSource to add it with c#).

```
namespace Chat.PresentationLayer.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Chat.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Chat : Page
    {
        private readonly UserManager userManager = new UserManager();

        public  List<UserViewModel> UsersList { get; set; } = new List<UserViewModel>();

        public UserViewModel SelectedUser { get; set; } = new UserViewModel();

        static bool b = true;

        public Chat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var users = userManager.GetAllUsers();

             //usersListBox.SelectionChanged += OnItemSelect;

            usersListBox.ItemsSource = users;
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                UsersList.Add(new UserViewModel { Id = user.Id, Username = user.Username, FirstName = user.FirstName, LastName = user.LastName });



                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();


                TextBox tb = new TextBox();

                Binding myBinding = new Binding();
                myBinding.Source = user;
                myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Username");
                myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(tb, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);



                sp.Children.Add(tb);

                DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate() { DataType = sp };

                usersListBox.ItemTemplate = dt;


                //The code below in comments represents exactly
                // what I want despite getting user Id after selecting.

                //usersListBox.Items.Add(user);

                //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
                //{
                //    if (user.Username == SessionInfo.CurrentUserInfo.Username)
                //    {

                //        usersListBox.Items.Add(user.Username + " (You)");
                //        continue;
                //    }

                //    usersListBox.Items.Add(user.Username);
                //    //usersListBox.ItemsSource = UsersList
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    if (user.Username == SessionInfo.CurrentUserInfo.Username)
                //    {

                //        usersListBox.Items.Add(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName + " (You)");
                //        continue;
                //    }
                //    usersListBox.Items.Add(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName);

                //}

            }

        }
```

*Note: The Binding part I added recently, before it the code was in this way:*

```
tb.Text = user.Username //it is pretty normal for this not to work, I know
```

This code actually doesn't work.
In ListBox there are Chat.BusinessLogicLayer.Models.UserViewModel instead of the name.
Result is the same without the whole foreach loop(which is pretty logical)
If I remove ItemSourse line, it won't add anything in listbox(in xaml it worked correctly without ItemSource property too, I don't know exactly why).

Thanks for any help!
Please, edit question title, I could not set anything better)

Comment: You could implement a "CalculatedUserName" within your UserViewModel and use this property for displaying the user name. The "CalculatedUserName" could return first and second name or Username. This way you wouldn't need to mess around with binding logic in the code behind.

Comment: And what about getting selected user id with SelectionChanged event? I think I have to "mess up" with Binding, because problem is to show some string properties in listbox, then get another after selecting it

Answer (score 0):

You should use XAML only. Just make `UserList` a `ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>` so that adding items to it will trigger the `ListBox` to update the content. This way you don't need any `foreach` anymore. Remove the initialization of `SelectedUser`. Create a view model for the (each) `Page`. Move all the page data initialization logic to the view model. Move model interaction (get users from database)  to the view model. Add a `IValueConverter` to the `TextBlock` binding to format the displayed username.

**PageViewModel.cs**

```
class ChatPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
  public ChatPageViewModel()
  {
    this.Users = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>();
  }

  private void OnSelectedUserChanged(UserViewModel selectedUser)
  {
    // TODO::Handle selected user
  }

  private bool CanInitializePage(object commandParameter)
  {
    return true;
  }

  private void InitializePage(object commandParameter)
  {
    this.Users = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>(userManager.GetAllUsers());
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  public ICommand InitializePageCommand => new RelayCommand(InitializePage, CanInitializePage);

  private UserViewModel selectedUser;
  public UserViewModel SelectedUser 
  {
    get => this.selectedUser;
    set
    {
      this.selectedUser = value;
      OnSelectedUserChanged();
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> users;
  public ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> Users 
  {
    get => this.users;
    set
    {
      this.users = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private UserManager userManager { get; } = new UserManager();
}
```

**UsernameFormatConverter.cs** (to format the username)

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(UserViewModel), typeof(string))]
public class UsernameFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is UserViewModel user)
    {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName)
        ? user.Username
        : user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName + " (You)";
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

**ChatPage.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="ChatPage">
  <Page.DataContext>
    <local:ChatPageVieModel />
  </Page.DataContext>
  <Page.Resources>
    <local:UsernameFormatConverter x:Key="UsernameFormatConverter" />
  </Page.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ListBox Name="usersListBox"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">

      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource UsernameFormatConverter}}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

**ChatPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Chat : Page
{
  public Chat()
  {
    this.Loaded += OnPageLoaded;
  }

  // I recommend to move page initialization to the code location where you load pages instead of doing it in the Loaded event handler
  private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {        
    if (this.DataContext is ChatPageViewModel viewModel 
        && viewModel.InitializePageCommand.canExecute(null))
    {
      viewModel.InitializePageCommand.Execute(null);
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, thank you, but one more question.Why can't I just replace xaml code with c# with the same result. I mean is it impossible to some kind of codes,or may be there is a way to do, but it is much more complicated, or it will use too much time and memory resources?

Comment: I tried to just replace xaml with c#, and I know it must be possible and it will be very useful for me knowing why isn't it working?

Comment: It's easier doing it in XAML.E.g. accessing resources and setting up bindings or triggers or the styling. It's more flexible and intuitive to design the UI using markup. Visual UI is structured like a tree. XAML notation reflects this structure and visualizes it. Therefore it s easier to maintain and to understand. Of course it is possible to do almost everything in C# only. But this would be terrible. Why do the work if the parser can do it for you? Please take a look on how to create a `DataTemplate` in C#: it's not convenient at all, too much code. Your code looks totally flawed.

Comment: What you have done wrong? Evrything?! Your `DataTemplate` is empty. You are setting `DataTemplate.DataType` to an instance of `StackPanel` instead of a `Type`. You need to manually create the visual tree of the template ( use `XamlReader ` or better use simple convenient XAML to create the template and let the XAML parser do the work. And you are overwriting all XAML settings and bindings. Your `Binding.Mode` on the `TextBox` is set to `TwoWay` but the `UserViewModel` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource` this is mandatory.

Comment: You are adding items to `ListBox.Items` instead of using the `ListBox.ItemsSource` bound collection. `UserList.Add()` will do nothing, because it is not an `ObservableCollection`. The `StackPanel` is not added to the visual tree of the `Page` so it will never show. Your `userManager.GetAllUsers();` is not async and will block the UI if there are many users. In this case the following `foreach` will block the UI a second time. Most of this errors wouldn't be there if you use XAML to create and design the UI.

Comment: The `ListBox` is bound to a collection of `UserViewModel` but in your C# code you are adding plain `string` objects to it (username etc). Because `ListBox.Items` is of type `object` this doesn't throw an error. That's why you should only add items to the collection that you bound to the `ItemsSource` because this collection is typed (in this case `List<UserViewModel`). Adding a `String` to it would have resulted in a compile time error. That's why you shouldn't add anything to `ItemsControl.Items` directly. There might be more mistakes in your code. I hope this helps.

Comment: To help you to understand it better you have to keep in mind that every assignment in code-behind will overwrite XAML declarations and bindings. `usersListBox.ItemTemplate = dt;` will remove the XAML defined template an replaces it with `dt`. But `dt` in your case is empty so the view will be empty too. Because `DataTemplate.DataType` is of type `object` `dt.DataType = sp` will not throw a compile time error. But if you'd have used XAML this would result in an error thrown from the parser (must be string or Type). The proper assignment is `dt.DataType = sp.GetType()`.

Comment: But you need to use `XamlReader` to create a `DataTemplate` anyway.

Comment: Well I'm rather new in wpf and xaml and don't understand it deeply enough to retpeat with c#. But I've worked with html and know "what it is made of ". Anyway, maybe that's why I didn't like templates at all.It was the first time I'm working with ItemTemplate and DataTemplate. I knew about adding in ItemsControl.Items directly, and that it was just strings, but I have to try. Don't reason straightly). Now I'm reading about ItemSource and DisplayMembersPath properties and hope to use it. Anyway, your answer helped a lot, thank you.

Comment: @HarutHunanyan Please, don't worry. WPF is not an easy framework. at all. You can't compare it to HTML and some JavaScript and expect to learn with the same effort. It  is more powerful, but also more complex. It's difficult to learn and requires time and patience. And the right attitude. I mean you need the will to learn it. You need to love reading and extending your knowledge. Please don't retreat. You are very close. Just read and follow some tutorials about styles and templates. You are almost there. Doing UI with C# is too complicated, as you can see with the `DataTemplate`. It's very v

Comment: @HarutHunanyan Just take your time to get over the first obstacle. It will be a lot easier from then on. But you need to take this steps. XAML is too important. You can't dodge it. Find yourself some good tutorial that you can understand and follow. Not every tutorial is good. And not every tutorial speaks your personal language or addresses your way of understanding and learning. If you have problems to follow or to connect to one, then find a better one.